# Unable to find alternatives for some Vue2 components in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am porting an old Vue2 project to Vue3, I am unable to find the alternative or updated components for some Vue2 components in Vue3. The project also uses vuetify so having some trouble here are some components I always get warning for:

```
chunk-DAILU36F.js?v=845f0d4d:3513 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-subheader
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>
warn2 @ chunk-DAILU36F.js?v=845f0d4d:3513
chunk-DAILU36F.js?v=845f0d4d:3513 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-list-item-content
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>
```

What should I do with such components? I am also changing the vuetify version for the App of course from vuetify2 to vuetify3

Comment: The question is too unspecific for SO. Check the migration section in vuetify docs, this is the first thing to search when you do any migration. As for other comps, there's a negligible chance that v2 comp works in 3 as is, search for alternatives, or try to rewrite them to 3, or write them from scratch, it's up to you

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#v-list